# How to terminate exec() function in python if it takes too long?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a function that takes in user's code and runs it:

```
code = input("Your code: ")

def execute(c):
    exec(c)
    
execute(code)
```

However, if the user enters in an infinite loop, the function runs forever.

Is there a way to terminate the `exec()` function if the function takes too long? For example, if the code takes longer than 15 seconds to execute, the programme terminates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to execute the code in a separate process which can be terminated then by the main process.

Comment: you can use `import sys
sys.exit()`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions,
For example you could pass a global variable stop condition and raise exception from inside the exec once condition has met.
Other solution would be to run exec in a separate thread/process and sending some stop signal once desired.

Comment: What does it mean to run exec in a separate thread/process?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `wrapt_timeout_decorator`

```
from wrapt_timeout_decorator import *

@timeout(15)
def execute(c):
    exec(c)

code = input("Your code: ")
execute(code)
```

This will throw an exception if the function takes more than 15 sec to finish - `TimeoutError: Function execute timed out after 15.0 seconds`

Comment: On Windows there may be issues with this code as it has to use multiprocessing internally which needs special care.

Comment: But windows also has linux support

Comment: Since Win 10 but not earlier. Also it must be explicitly installed in Windows first and has restrictions when accessing Windows-specific things like the registry.